# Resolução Ionic

Tags: ionic

À mais ou menos 2 dias, começamos a montar ambiente para gerar um deploy para o Android, antes de começarmos, rodamos o comando `ionic serve --lab` e estava como queriamos... Após configurarmos e subirmos para a loja (em ambiente de teste), fizemos o download do app no celular e estava com a tela em branco...

Então voltamos para o codigo e abrimos em resoluções diferentes pelo inspecionar do google e ficou desta forma:

Sabem me dizer onde preciso dar uma atenção para ver se pode ser isso? Não sei onde ver porque foi logo apos configurar o ambiente mesmo...

WEB
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Galaxy S5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

IPAD PRO
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Voltei 14 commits e fui testando arquivo por arquivo e vendo o que podia ter influenciado...

Até que vi alterações no `tsconfig` e descartei e voltou a funcionar, agora vou entender o que eram essas alterações...